# how to disable a button which is present in a dyanamic list when clicked in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let product of products" no-padding>
   <ion-item>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="qty" *ngIf="product.type==variable" [disabled]="false">
        <ion-option value="1">1kg</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="250">250gm</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="500">500gm</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="100">100gm</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <button [disabled]=disable color="light" class="addbtn" ion-button clear (click)="addlist(product.name,product.id,product.price*product.quantity,product.quantity,product.images[0].src)">ADD</button>
 </ion-card>
```

this is my ts

```
var disable=false;
addlist(name, id, price, qty, image) {
  //it is disabling each button present in the list 
  this.disable=true;
}
```

Comment: on which condition you want to disable it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong crearly is that you're using the same `disable` property for every item in your array, you'll need a specific `disable` for every item in your array.

I see two ways of doing this:

- You can iterate through your `products` and add a `disable` property. If it's coming from a server and if you can and want, you can add the property there so you don't waste a little time doing this in your front-end.
- You can create a new array of `disable` and use your *ngFor indexes to access the correct disable for every item.

#### The first option is something like:

In your .ts file you'll have:

```
// Let's say you're fetching your products in a lifecyclehook like ionViewDidLoad
ionViewDidLoad = () => {
  // your call for the api...
  myHttpCall.then(prods => {
    this.products = prods;
    // let's use map to iterate through the products
    this.products.map(item => {
      // this'll create a property in every item of your array.
      item.disabled = false;
    })
  })
}

addlist(name, id, price, qty, image, product) {
  // you'll need to pass the entire object to your method, and then set the property to true.
  product.disabled = true;
}
```

I could have used map directly on the response, or a spread operator, but let's aim for the simplest.

In your html:

```
<!-- All your card code. Change the disabled of the button and the select as bellow -->
<button [disabled]="product.disabled" color="light" class="addbtn" ion-button clear (click)="addlist(product.name,product.id,product.price*product.quantity,product.quantity,product.images[0].src, product)">ADD</button>
<!-- Just pass the entire product in the end of the method -->
```

#### The second option:

In your .ts you'll create a new array and for every item in products you'll push a new boolean:

```
export class YourPage {
  // the new boolean array
  public disabled: Array<boolean> = [];

  // The method where you get the products, same as the first option
  ionViewDidLoad = () => {
    // your call for the api...
    myHttpCall.then(prods => {
      this.products = prods;
      // use a for to iterate through
      for (let i =  0; i < this.products.length; i++){
        this.disabled.push(false);
      }
    })
  }

  addlist(name, id, price, qty, image, index) {
    // now you'll pass the index from the ngfor
    // you'll access the corresponding disable from the array and set to true
    this.disabled[index] = true;
  }
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<!-- declare the index in your ngFor -->
<ion-card *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" no-padding>
   <ion-item>
      <!-- change the disable to reflect the correct array position -->
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="qty" *ngIf="product.type==variable" [disabled]="disabled[i]">
        <ion-option value="1">1kg</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="250">250gm</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="500">500gm</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="100">100gm</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <!-- Add the index in the end of your click method -->
    <button [disabled]="disabled[i]" color="light" class="addbtn" ion-button clear (click)="addlist(product.name,product.id,product.price*product.quantity,product.quantity,product.images[0].src, i)">ADD</button>
 </ion-card>
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: @kritisharma glad it worked, so please accept my answer as correct, it can help other people find this solution

Comment: Ya sure:) @GabrielBarreto

Answer (score 0):

In your component make a `loop` of `products` and add `disable` property based on your required `condition`:

```
for (let product of products) {
    product.disabled = false;
    if(product.somefield == 'somevalue'){
      product.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

**In html** take `button disabled` property as,  `[disabled]="product.disabled"`

```
<button [disabled]="product.disabled" color="light" class="addbtn" ion-button clear (click)="addlist(product.name,product.id,product.price*product.quantity,product.quantity,product.images[0].src)">ADD</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but i dont have any value to satisfy this condition its just like I have clicked the button once and its just get disabled